# How to translate a label of a custom field in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, custom-fields

I have created a custom field in Opportunities, but I also have to translate its label into Russian and there is no option for it in the "Edit labels" menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to create translated labels without Studio.

Main idea is that module string label is a value of *$mod_strings* array key which is defined in language file(s) located in modules//language/ , custom/modules//language/ and/or custom/modules/Accounts/Ext/Language/*.lang.ext.php

Thus to have an existing string in English translated into your native language manually you should do the following:

1. Copy your English string to be translated in browser (e.g. *"Description"*)
2. Use your IDE or OS find/search function to find needed $mod_strings key that has value of the string above (e.g. *$mod_strings['LBL_DESCRIPTION']*)
3. Copy that key name
4. Change to custom/Extension/modules//Ext/Language (so called [Master Directory](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9003219)) and create new (or append to existing) file named (in your case) ru_ru.custom.lang.php
5. Add a line like

   $mod_strings['LBL_DESCRIPTION'] = 'Описание';
6. Make Quick Repair and Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Studio » Contacts » Labels,

then you can see that label and then select

> 'US English' or 'Russian'

from the language drop down.

Comment: I know about that dropdown, but when i choose Russian, my custom label disappears.

Comment: Choose Russian first, then change the value.

Comment: What if you have to support several languages? 30+